# What is the fastest\best way to get file names from a folder using PowerShell?

Tags: .net, powershell, getfiles

The directory has 20k folders in it. In these folders there are subfolders and some files. I don't need to look into the subfolders. I need to get all the files with .EIA extension from the folders.

I know I could use Get-Item, Get-ChildItem for this but these cmdlet are too slow in the getting the data. Also, this script has to run every hour therefore, it cannot be taking superlong.

I was trying to use  `[System.IO.File]::GetFiles($path)` but this gives an error

```
 Method invocation failed because [System.IO.File] does not contain a method named 'GetFile'
```

I have also tried

```
$pathEia = "\\Sidney2\MfgLib\AidLibTest\*\*.EIA"
 [System.IO.File]::GetFiles($pathEia)
```

This also throws an error:

```
 Exception calling "GetFiles" with "1" argument(s): "The filename, directory name, or volume label
     | syntax is incorrect. : '\\Sidney2\MfgLib\AidLibTest\*\*.EIA'"
```

I am using
PowerShell Core 7.2
.Net Framework 4.8
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: generally speaking, the fastest way to get the file names from a large dir tree _on windows_ is to use `robocopy`. [*grin*] you can use the options to have it present you with just the full path & file name ... and it is FAST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very similar to [mklement0's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72324922/15339544) but using the instance methods from [`DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=net-6.0).

[`EnumerationOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.enumerationoptions?view=net-6.0) is available starting from **.NET Core 2.1**. This class has the property [`IgnoreInaccessible`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.enumerationoptions.ignoreinaccessible?view=net-6.0#system-io-enumerationoptions-ignoreinaccessible) set to `$true` by default, **in prior versions an exception would cause the enumeration to Stop**:

> ...skip files or directories when access is denied (for example, [UnauthorizedAccessException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.unauthorizedaccessexception?view=net-6.0) or [SecurityException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securityexception?view=net-6.0)).

This answer **requires PowerShell Core 7+**.

```
# Skip the following Attributes:
#   2.    Hidden
#   4.    System
#   1024. ReparsePoint
#   512.  SparseFile

$enum = [IO.EnumerationOptions]@{
    RecurseSubdirectories = $false # Set to `$true` if you need to do a recursive search
    AttributesToSkip      = 2, 4, 1024, 512
}

$start  = [IO.DirectoryInfo]::new('\\Sidney2\MfgLib\AidLibTest')
$result = foreach($dir in $start.EnumerateDirectories()) {
    $dir.GetFiles('*.EIA', $using:enum)
}
$result | Format-Table
```

---

If you need to do a recursive search on the subfolders (if `RecurseSubdirectories = $true`), you can consider using *multi-threading* with [`ForEach-Object -Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-11-run-slow-script-in-parallel-batches).

```
$start  = [IO.DirectoryInfo]::new('\\Sidney2\MfgLib\AidLibTest')
$result = $start.EnumerateDirectories() | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    $_.GetFiles('*.EIA', $using:enum)
}
$result | Format-Table
```

It's important to note that, using a *parallel loop* **may or may not** have an edge over an efficient linear loop (such as [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.2)), as [mklement0 notes in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72324803/what-is-the-fastest-best-way-to-get-file-names-from-a-folder-using-powershell/72325130?noredirect=1#comment127850519_72325130):

> Parallelism works best for different disks/shares/computers.

Comment: Using the `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` instance methods is indeed useful for accessing the properties of the `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances returned, such as if you want the file _names_ only. Showing the pitfalls of enumeration is helpful, though probably not needed in this case. However, note that `ForEach-Object -Parallel` _slows things down_ when you're targeting a single folder: In my tests with 200 subdirs. containing 10 files of interest each, a regular, non-parallel `foreach` statement outperforms a `ForEach-Object -Parallel` by a factor of around 50(!).

Comment: @mklement0 that's interesting, could you share a gist with the code to reproduce? here are my findings, I see a better (tho minuscule) advantage using runspaces https://gist.github.com/santysq/98e69bb59286f2baebc56d346fdd37d1 I presume, the advantage will increase the more folders there are

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/mklement0/d25dff3f2a24ef9b24b80e647d776467 - note that it creates a subfolder `./tf` in the current folder and removes it again afterwards. My `Time-Command` function is downloaded on demand (I looked at the Benchpress module you pointed me to, which is more polished overall, but I prefer `Time-Command` for some additional work to level the playing field, such as running the garbage collector between tests).

Comment: @mklement0 agree that parallel is slower in this test, tho I don't see the point of running in parallel for 2000 files. the linear loop can enumerate the files the time it takes to create the runspaces in this case I believe

Comment: @Brute yes, `$result.Directory.Name` will give you the name of the parent folder of each file

Comment: Note that the premise of the question is 20,000 subfolders inside a single folder, with the files of interest inside those folders - no recursion needed. Just ran a test with this number of subfolders and 10 files in each; the slowdown with parallelism is about 25-fold(!) with the default throttle limit of 5. Based on your benchmarks, I conclude the following: When targeting a single disk, parallel threads can provide a speed benefit if each thread needs to perform deeply nested recursion; if not, they are likely to slow things down. Parallelism works best for different disks/shares/computers.

Comment: @mklement0 agreed, after testing using 20k subfolders without recursion it's clearly bad

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```bash
$path = '\\Sidney2\MfgLib\AidLibTest'
$allFilePathsOfInterest =
  foreach ($dir in [System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories($path)) {
    [System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles($dir, '*.EIA')
  }
```

Given that the input directory path is a *full* path, `$allFilesOfInterest` is an array of full file paths too.

If you want the file *names* only, use the *instance* methods of  the [`[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) type instead of the *static* methods of the [`[System.IO.Directory]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.Directory) type, which allows you to access the `.Name` property of the [`[System.IO.FileInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances being returned:

```bash
$path = '\\Sidney2\MfgLib\AidLibTest'
$allFileNamesOfInterest =
  foreach ($dir in [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]::new($path).GetDirectories()) {
    $dir.GetFiles('*.EIA').Name
  }
```

- Note the two-step approach - get subdirectories first, then examine their files - because I'm not aware of a standard .NET API that would allow you to process wildcards across levels of the hierarchy (e.g., `\\Sidney2\MfgLib\AidLibTest\*\*.EIA'`).
- If you need more control over the enumeration of the files and directories, the [`GetDirectories`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories) and [`GetFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.Directory.GetFiles) methods offer overloads that accept a [`System.IO.EnumerationOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.EnumerationOptions) instance, but, unfortunately, in PowerShell (Core) 7+ / .NET (Core) only:

  - Windows PowerShell / .NET Framework only offers overloads with a [`System.IO.SearchOption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.SearchOption) instance, but the only thing that controls is whether the enumeration is *recursive*.